# Lattice's `panel.rug` produces different line length with wide plot

Tags: r, data-visualization, lattice

When producing a wide plot in lattice with margins that include `panel.rug()`, the length of the lines in *rugged* margins is longer in the y-axis than x-axis:

```
library(lattice)
png(width=800, height=400)
xyplot(Fertility ~ Education, swiss, panel = function(x, y,...) {
  panel.xyplot(x, y, col=1, pch=16)
  panel.rug(x, y, col=1, end= ...)})
dev.off()
```

[image]

I would like those *rug* lines in x- and y-axes to be the same length regardless of the shape of a plot (note: right now the *rug* lines will only be the same length when the plot is square).

Comment: Maybe post this as two separate questions, one for **lattice** and  one for **ggplot2**?

Comment: Good point, will do, quite different graphical systems so it makes sense to separate it...

Comment: Yeah, especially since (given what's displayed on your nifty [Tufte in R page](http://motioninsocial.com/tufte/)), I'm guessing you want answers for **both**, rather than just for one or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With **lattice**,  just change the coordinate system used by `panel.rug`  from its default (`"npc"`) to `"snpc"`:

```
library(lattice)

## png(width=800, height=400)
xyplot(Fertility ~ Education, swiss, panel = function(x, y,...) {
  panel.xyplot(x, y, col=1, pch=16)
  panel.rug(x = x, y = y,  
            x.units = rep("snpc", 2),  y.units = rep("snpc", 2), 
            col=1, end= ...)
})
## dev.off()
```

[image]

To see *why* this gets you what you want, refer to `?unit` for its description of what those two coordinate systems mean:

```
 Possible ‘units’ (coordinate systems) are:

 ‘"npc"’ Normalised Parent Coordinates (the default).  The origin
      of the viewport is (0, 0) and the viewport has a width and
      height of 1 unit.  For example, (0.5, 0.5) is the centre of
      the viewport.

 ‘"snpc"’ Square Normalised Parent Coordinates.  Same as Normalised
      Parent Coordinates, except gives the same answer for
      horizontal and vertical locations/dimensions.  It uses the
      _lesser_ of npc-width and npc-height.  This is useful for
      making things which are a proportion of the viewport, but
      have to be square (or have a fixed aspect ratio).
```