# ggplot2 geom_rug() produces different line length with wide plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I posted this as follow up to a 'sibling' question with lattice (i.e. [Lattice's `panel.rug` produces different line length with wide plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222841/lattices-panel-rug-and-ggplots-geom-rug-line-length#33223071)) but due to different graphical system it deserves to be separate.

When producing a wide plot in ggplot2 with margins that include `geom_rug()` from `ggthemes`, the length of the lines in rugged margins is longer in the y-axis than x-axis:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
png(width=800, height=400)
ggplot(swiss, aes(Education, Fertility)) + geom_point() + geom_rug()
dev.off()
```

[image]

I would like those *rug* lines in x- and y-axes to be the same length regardless of the shape of a plot (note: right now the *rug* lines will only be the same length when the plot is square).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This followed hadley's <strike>current</strike> previous `geom_rug` code, but modified it to add (or subtract) an absolute amount for interior units of the rug-ticks. It's really an application of the `grid::unit`-function more than anything else, since it uses the fact that units can be added and subtracted with different bases. You could modify it to accept a "rug_len"-argument with a default of your choosing, say unit(0.5, "cm"). (Do need to remember to set the `environment` of the function, so that one closure, `geom_rug2`, can call the next closure, `ggplot2::'+'`, correctly.)

```
geom_rug2 <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", position = "identity", sides = "bl", ...) {
  GeomRug2$new(mapping = mapping, data = data, stat = stat, position = position, sides = sides, ...)
}

GeomRug2 <- proto(ggplot2:::Geom, {
  objname <- "rug2"

  draw <- function(., data, scales, coordinates, sides, ...) {
    rugs <- list()
    data <- coord_transform(coordinates, data, scales)
    if (!is.null(data$x)) {
      if(grepl("b", sides)) {
        rugs$x_b <- segmentsGrob(
          x0 = unit(data$x, "native"), x1 = unit(data$x, "native"),
          y0 = unit(0, "npc"), y1 = unit(0, "npc")+unit(1, "cm"),
          gp = gpar(col = alpha(data$colour, data$alpha), lty = data$linetype, lwd = data$size * .pt)
        )
      }

      if(grepl("t", sides)) {
        rugs$x_t <- segmentsGrob(
          x0 = unit(data$x, "native"), x1 = unit(data$x, "native"),
          y0 = unit(1, "npc"), y1 = unit(1, "npc")-unit(1, "cm"),
          gp = gpar(col = alpha(data$colour, data$alpha), lty = data$linetype, lwd = data$size * .pt)
        )
      }
    }

    if (!is.null(data$y)) {
      if(grepl("l", sides)) {
        rugs$y_l <- segmentsGrob(
          y0 = unit(data$y, "native"), y1 = unit(data$y, "native"),
          x0 = unit(0, "npc"), x1 = unit(0, "npc")+unit(1, "cm"),
          gp = gpar(col = alpha(data$colour, data$alpha), lty = data$linetype, lwd = data$size * .pt)
        )
      }

      if(grepl("r", sides)) {
        rugs$y_r <- segmentsGrob(
          y0 = unit(data$y, "native"), y1 = unit(data$y, "native"),
          x0 = unit(1, "npc"), x1 = unit(1, "npc")-unit(1, "cm"),
          gp = gpar(col = alpha(data$colour, data$alpha), lty = data$linetype, lwd = data$size * .pt)
        )
      }
    }

    gTree(children = do.call("gList", rugs))
  }

  default_stat <- function(.) StatIdentity
  default_aes <- function(.) aes(colour="black", size=0.5, linetype=1, alpha = NA)
  guide_geom <- function(.) "path"
})
environment(geom_rug2) <- environment(ggplot)

p <- qplot(x,y)
p + geom_rug2(size=.1)
```

With your code creating a png I get:

[image]

Comment: +1 for demonstrating how to create a new geom based on an old one. A seemingly even simpler edit to that function is to just replace all occurrences of `"npc"` in the function returned by `get("draw", ggplot2:::GeomRug)` with the string `"snpc"`.

Comment: "spnc".... good one! I had never heard of 'snpc' before. Although I was looking at the `?unit` page, I didn't look at it very carefully. Could leave the current "npc" units in and put in a rug_scale argument. Paging @hadley.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't come up too often. [Here's the only other place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015110/color-a-designated-area/13015631#13015631) I've ever demo'd it on SO.

Comment: And now you've additionally demonstrated my failing memory as well as my lack of attention to printed documentation. I already gave you as much credit back then. That _was_ a very nice  effort on your part .

Comment: Hey, if you'd have been able to remember two characters in a post you last read 3 years ago, **that** would be something to worry about ;) I just thought that was a fun blast from the past.

Comment: @BondedDust This is indeed a good function deconstruction:) Is it ok if I drop your `geom_rug2()` on `GitHub`? I wanted to be able to retrieve it easily for my side project (of course attribution will be accordingly provided)?

Comment: Of course, you may put it on Github. Primary author is Hadley Wickham and he gave it a License: GPL-2 in his DESCRIPTION file  and my editing authorship is relatively minor, so I'll just follow him and "license" it as  GPL-2. The grid package is Paul Murrell's.

Comment: @42- Sorry to bother you about this, but somehow after those few months the function displays an error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "eval". I Googled but can't find the relevant solution. From the top of your head would you know what might cause it? The function is now [here on Github](https://github.com/GeekOnAcid/geom_rug2/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: "Could not find the function `eval`" sounds like a fairly serious disturbance in the Force. Hadley recently changed the underlying mechanism for proto objects. I haven' been able to penetrate the "ggproto Curtain", however.

Comment: Looking at these last couple of  comments I'm now wondering if using `assignInNamespace` might be a more effective approach to building a new geom?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if there's a way to control the rug segment length in `geom_rug` (I couldn't find one). However, you can create your own rug using `geom_segment` and hard-code the segment lengths or add some logic to programatically produce equal-length rug lines. For example:

```
# Aspect ratio
ar = 0.33

# Distance from lowest value to start of rug segment
dist = 2

# Rug length factor
rlf = 2.5

ggplot(swiss, aes(Education, Fertility)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_segment(aes(y=Fertility, yend=Fertility, 
                   x=min(swiss$Education) - rlf*ar*dist, xend=min(swiss$Education) - ar*dist)) +
  geom_segment(aes(y=min(swiss$Fertility) - rlf*dist, yend=min(swiss$Fertility) - dist, 
                   x=Education, xend=Education)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio=ar,
              xlim=c(min(swiss$Education) - rlf*ar*dist, 1.03*max(swiss$Education)),
              ylim=c(min(swiss$Fertility) - rlf*dist, 1.03*max(swiss$Fertility)))
```

[image]

Or if you just want to hard-code it:

```
ggplot(swiss, aes(Education, Fertility)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_segment(aes(y=Fertility, yend=Fertility, 
                   x=min(swiss$Education) - 3, xend=min(swiss$Education) - 1.5)) +
  geom_segment(aes(y=min(swiss$Fertility) - 6, yend=min(swiss$Fertility) - 3, 
                   x=Education, xend=Education)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(min(swiss$Education) - 3, 1.03*max(swiss$Education)),
                  ylim=c(min(swiss$Fertility) - 6, 1.03*max(swiss$Fertility)))
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without changing the aspect ratio?

Comment: See updated answer. I've added a way to hard-code it that doesn't set the aspect ratio. However, note that you'll have to tweak the values so that they work with whatever implicit aspect ratio you choose when you save the plot.

Comment: Having looked through the code, I would say there is definitely no way to control rug tick lengths in the current version.

Answer (score 3):

As of ggplot2 [v3.2.0](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#ggplot2-3-2-0) you can pass a length argument to geom_rug() to specify the absolute length of the rug:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
png(width=800, height=400)
ggplot(swiss, aes(Education, Fertility)) + geom_point() + geom_rug(length = unit(0.5,"cm"))
dev.off()
```

[image: Fixed Length Geom_rug]

Answer (score 2):

Delving into the structure of the ggplot grob:

**Minor edit: updating to ggplot2 2.2.1**

```
library(ggplot2)
p = ggplot(swiss, aes(Education, Fertility)) + geom_point() + geom_rug()

# Get the ggplot grob
gp = ggplotGrob(p)

# Set end points of rug segments
library(grid)
gp$grobs[[6]]$children[[4]]$children[[1]]$y1 = unit(0.03, "snpc")
gp$grobs[[6]]$children[[4]]$children[[2]]$x1 = unit(0.03, "snpc")

png(width=900, height=300)
grid.draw(gp)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another under-the-hood solution. First, I get the ggplot grob, and then I use the `editGrob` function from the `grid` package. With `editGrob`, I simply name the grob to be edited; it's easier than having to follow the grob's structure all the way to the relevant parameters. Normally, `editGrob` can't see all of the ggplot grobs, but they can be exposed with `grid.force()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

p = ggplot(swiss, aes(Education, Fertility)) + geom_point() + geom_rug() 

# Get the ggplot grob
gp = ggplotGrob(p)

# Get names of relevant grobs.
# The grid.force function generates the gtable's at-drawing-time contents.
names.grobs = grid.ls(grid.force(gp))$name # We're interested in the children of rugs.gTree
segments = names.grobs[which(grepl("GRID.segments", names.grobs))]

# Check them out
str(getGrob(grid.force(gp), gPath(segments[1]))) # Note: y1 = 0.03 npc
str(getGrob(grid.force(gp), gPath(segments[2]))) # Note: x1 = 0.03 npc

# Set y1 and x1 to 0.03 snpc
gp = editGrob(grid.force(gp), gPath(segments[1]), y1 = unit(0.03, "snpc"))
gp = editGrob(grid.force(gp), gPath(segments[2]), x1 = unit(0.03, "snpc"))

png(width=900, height=300)
grid.draw(gp)
dev.off()
```